# Interpret Data produced by View Component ASP Razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using a View Component to create a portion of an MVC Page. The View component goes to a database, and produces a table of results if the query produces results. The query producing results means there's a problem, so I've set up the view component to only display if there were results. This query is meant to be re-usable in different parts of the site, too, because its results can impact multiple pages.

Works great for showing the error only when it's an issue!

However, the main page has a form handler for sending an E-Mail message, and I want to disable that capability when the data is invalid. I use `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` to check whether the model is valid or not. However, because my Component is indicating whether or not the data is valid, I've run into an issue!

I have no idea how to check whether the component is populated or not, without somehow hardcoding it back to the original page. I can't seem to pass view data from the Component to the calling page (although the other direction works great), I can't even subscribe the page to an event because I see no way to associate the Component instance with the page!

I don't need to check the contents of the component before invalidating the page, I just need to know whether or not the component produced anything at all.

Can anybody help me do this?

Here is the code for the Component:

```
namespace Reports.Shared.Validation
{
    public class IdentifierValidationViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IdentifierValidationDB _IdentifierValidationContext;

        public IdentifierValidationViewComponent(IdentifierValidationDB IdentifierValidationContext)
        {
            _IdentifierValidationContext = IdentifierValidationContext;
        }

        public List<IdentifierValidation> InvalidIdentifiers { get; set; }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string date)
        {
            InvalidIdentifiers = await _IdentifierValidationContext.IdentifierValidations.FromSqlRaw("EXEC Reports.IdentifierValidation {0}", date).ToListAsync();

            return View(InvalidIdentifiers);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Partial View that the Component is rendering:

```
@model List<Reports.Models.Shared.Validation.IdentifierValidation>


@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div id="InvalidIdentifiers" class="alert-danger">
        <h2>Values are missing Identifiers!</h2>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var invalid in Model)
            {
            <li>
                @invalid.SecName has no Identifier.
            </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Finally, I invoke the component on the main page with this line

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("IdentifierValidation", new { date = Model.Date })
```

All I want to do is have the main page check if the component is actually producing any HTML or not, and then invalidate `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` if so.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

In my case, because I only need to check during the initial load of the page whether or not the table has produced results, and because the status doesn't need to be retained between refreshes, I can use `ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[]` to store a flag indicating whether or not the table has been populated. I needed to make changes to the Component and the main page, but with the following changes, it seems to work!

Controller:

```
namespace Reports.Shared.Validation
{
    public class IdentifierValidationViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IdentifierValidationDB _IdentifierValidationContext;

        public IdentifierValidationViewComponent(IdentifierValidationDB IdentifierValidationContext)
        {
            _IdentifierValidationContext = IdentifierValidationContext;
        }

        public List<IdentifierValidation> InvalidIdentifiers { get; set; }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string date)
        {
            InvalidIdentifiers = await _IdentifierValidationContext.IdentifierValidations.FromSqlRaw("EXEC Reports.IdentifierValidation {0}", date).ToListAsync();

            if(InvalidIdentifiers.Count() > 0)
            {
                ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["InvalidIdentifier"] = "Detected";
            }

            return View(InvalidIdentifiers);
        }
    }
}
```

And now, we can invoke the controller as such:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("IdentifierValidation", new { date = Model.Date })
@if (ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["InvalidIdentifier"] != null)
{
    ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("InvalidIdentifier", "An Invalid Identifier has been Detected!");
}
```

When we do this, we are invalidating the model state only if the partial produced results when it was loaded on page refresh!

Of course, if you're doing something fancier with it, like using javascript/ajax to refresh the content of the partial on the client side, this will not work.